# C/C++ Reflection and JNI - A method for invoking native code which hasn't been written yet

Tags: c++, c, reflection, java-native-interface

I am implementing a piece of Java software that will hopefully allow for C libraries as plugins. In order to call these future functions, I need to somehow create a native function in Java from which I can call the code that doesn't exist yet. The method signature will be static but the method and class names may change.

Is there a way to check the loaded libraries or available functions? The way I hope it would work would be as follows:

In my Java class I would have a function;

```
public static native void thirdParty(String class, String method, int[] data, int[] params);
```

Which would call a function in my C library;

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_ex_app_Native_thirdParty(JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jstring, jintArray, jintArray);
```

From which I could take the class and method name and call them if they exist and throw an exception if they don't.

I guess what I'm looking for is some kind of Java style reflection but in C or failing that C++.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way (or common since there is no real standard)

Is to create a DLL (shared lib).
That DLL has a "C" function with a a fixed name that returns a pointer to a factory object.
You can then use the factory to build objects.

Example:

```
DLL-> Wdigets1.dll      C function -> extern "C" Fac& getWidgetFactory();  
DLL-> BoilerWidget.dll  C function -> extern "C" Fac& getWidgetFactory();  
DLL-> RoundWidget.dll   C function -> extern "C" Fac& getWidgetFactory();
```

Thus whatever dll you load all you need to do is get a pointer to the function getWidgetFactory() and now you can use the factory to build the appropriate widgets.

The reason behind this:
The libraries that allow you to load libraries dynamically also allow you to find methods/function by name. But the name you need to use is the full name. In "C" this is well defined. In "C++" this is the mangeled name and varies across compilers/platforms etc. So portable code can only find "C" names.

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ don't really have Java-style reflection (though sometimes you can play tricks with looking up symbols in a shared library).

A more typical approach is to create a plugin interface in Java.  Then for each external library, you write a (hopefully) small amount of custom Java and/or JNI code to translate plugin interface calls to calls to the backend library.

Comment: Does this approach require new java code for each plugin? Each plugin provides a method with the same parameters but performs a different calculation.

The java code will be fixed after installation and I want to support different C plugin libraries.

Sorry If this is the question you already answered, I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: For each new C plugin, there would need to be a small amount of accompanying new Java code that translates the Java calls to the C calls.  This approach assumes that you don't have control over the C libraries (Martin York's answer is the best if you do control the C libraries).  I haven't used JNA, but Matthew Flaschen's suggestion looks like it might be an alternative to my suggestion when you don't control the C code.

Comment: Since JNI code tends to be a dynamic library anyway, C code could do exactly what the VM does when accessing pre-existing JNI methods, which is use name resolution requests to the dynamic linker to access loaded functions - in effect this is very much like reflection.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/), which basically allows you to lookup and call native functions from Java without writing custom JNI code.  It uses the libffi foreign function library.

Answer (score 0):

> The method signature will be static but the method and class names may change.

In C++ the method name and the class name are what determine what function you're calling, and are used to create the symbol JNI looks for (this is called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B)).

There is hope.  The [plugin systems I'm familiar with](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/204202899) require that each plugin implement a C function with a particular name and signature (in C++ you must mark this function as `extern "C"`), that will call whatever other functions and libraries needed, and the plugin system keeps track of which DLLs (Windows)/SOs (UNIX) belong to which plugin, and call the magic function from the corresponding file.

Since JNI requires a file and a function name, this is a straightforward way to implement your plugin system.