# How can I separate JNI part from the Android app?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am writing an Android application. I am implementing some of the app in C++ using JNI. Is there a way to actually separate completely the JNI (C++) code from the Java Android code? Like creating a JNI project or something ? Because my C++ code will become a little library that I will use in another app. I tried to create a C++ project but I can't compile with ndk-build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JNI in your C++ code, then it's bound to Android, and it must be an Android project with properly defined `Android.mk`, `Application.mk`(optional).

If you don't use JNI API in your code, say you want to create a generic library, you can just write your C++ code, compile it, test it as usual, no `ndk-build` is needed. When you finish coding with the library, build the code as a static library, and when you want to use this static library in your Android project, write some JNI wrappers around functionalities in the static library that you want to use, link against the static library in your `Android.mk`, something like this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libgeneric
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libgeneric.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Simply not true.  While it's easiest to run ndk-build out of something that resembles an Android project structure, that's not the only way you can build a jni library.  Or, you can have a dummy android project structure with only the jni code in it - the actual app(s) can be elsewhere.  Also the "static library" comment here is a bit unclear about the fact that the static libary **would have to be built with an Android compiler** such as the ndk's.  Building it first for something else (like the dev machine) is useful, but it must be recompiled to target each Android ABI of interest.

Answer (score 1):

In actuality, the tie-in between the Java and native code is fairly loose, in that it is done by the names of the methods at runtime.

The NDK is just a special environment and libraries for a C compiler.  A suitable dynamic library file must be produced, but this can be done using the ndk script, using an ndk generated "stand alone tool chain" or even done before (or after, see later) the java project build, done on another machine, etc.

Normally the .so dynamic library gets copied into the appropriate place in the application project tree such that it will end up packaged in the .apk and installed on the device where it can be automatically found by the System.loadLibrary() method.  But you could just insert it into the otherwise finished .apk (which is a zip file with special alignment and jarsigner signatures).  But even the .pak is not actually not the only way to deliver it to the device (though it is the only recommended way)- a library can also be stored in a place such as the app's private folder and loaded using System.load() which takes a full pathname instead of a library name.

hotverspicy does have a point that the java code needs a native method "declaration" for what is implemented in the jni library, and that this needs to match the actual package name as encoded in the name of the native function implementation.  However, that package name does not have to be the same as the rest of the java code - it could be something generic for the re-usable C/C++ library, which would require only one brief matching java class file in the matching java package name.

But in addition to Neevek's idea of using one native lib to interface to another, it is also likely possible to use an object factory mechanism to hook up arbitrary native functions at runtime, given just one association set up at compile time - see the relevant answer to [C/C++ Reflection and JNI - A method for invoking native code which hasn't been written yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958456/c-c-reflection-and-jni-a-method-for-invoking-native-code-which-hasnt-been-w)